# How to use AWS user pool access tokens to access AWS resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cognito

I have been using AWS cognito to create users and issue access tokens. I did this by setting up a custom domain (to sign in) and allowing implicit code grant etc...

Next I set up a identity pool which gives access to s3 objects through cloudfront. Then I added the user pool as a provider using the id and client ID.

I got to my oauth domain, logged in, then got my access token in the url. All well and good.

I finally sent a request to my original cloudfront domain to try and access my private s3 object. However the request was not allowed.

This lead me to have a few questions:

**How do I associate the access token to IAM role? Does AWS not pick up the access token and add the IAM roles to the request automatically? Do I have to make another request to the identity pool to get another token with IAM role information?**

**Do I have to put custom authorizers infront of cloudfront like Authorization@Edge?**

**I also have an ALB and lambda functions. Do I need to add custom authorizers for each of these to tranform the access token to IAM roles for each request. Is there a common way for all?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get the session aws credentials from the id_token? maybe you are missing that part

Comment: I think this is the part I have. It's getting AWS IAM access right after this which is the problem. I think I should use what I mentioned above but still a bit unsure.